# How to convert float to binary without using unsafe code?

Tags: floating-point, rust, ieee-754

Is there a way to convert a floating point number (`f32` or `f64`) to a data type that I can access bitwise, like `u32`/`u64`? That is, something corresponding to:

```
fn as_bits(i: f64) -> u64 {
    unsafe { mem::transmute(i) }
}
```

but without the `unsafe`. This code is safe per the [rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/meet-safe-and-unsafe.html), even though it may not return the same values on all platforms, specifically for NaNs. The reverse safe interface would also be nice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Rust 1.20 introduced [`f64::to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.to_bits) and [`f32::to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org//std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_bits):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", (4.2f64).to_bits())
}
```

Before then, you need to use the unsafe function `transmute`. They produce the same result:

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let float = 4.2f64;

    let via_method = float.to_bits();
    let via_transmute: u64 = unsafe { mem::transmute(float) };

    assert_eq!(via_method, via_transmute);    
}
```