# Why does f32 not implement std::fmt::Binary?

Tags: rust

I am trying to display a `f32` in binary format:

```
let value: f32 = 0.45;
let my_string = format!("{:b}", value);
```

I get the following error: "the trait bound `f32: std::fmt::Binary` is not satisfied".

I think we have to implement the trait by ourselves when we want to have a binary representation of a `f32` into a `String`. In fact, Rust doesn't know what to do for some `f32` values that cannot be represented in binary. For example, what to do with `0.1` ? Should the trait return the string `0.00011` or `0.0001100110011`? Is this the reason why there is no definition of `std::fmt::Binary` for `f32`?

Comment: Note that OP is asking **why**, not **how**. How is already covered in [How to convert float to binary without using unsafe code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377657/155423) as integers can be printed in binary.

Comment: @Shepmaster, I think the other question refers to conversion to the underlying bit pattern, not formatting the floating point value as text, in radix 2.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer good point! However, OP is still asking for **why**, so any answer *must* address that point. Usually these types of questions rely on internal knowledge of one or more Rust developers and thus can never be answered. However, my mistake adds one potential reason: because there are multiple incompatible ways of parsing "print this value as binary".

Comment: I don't think there is any fundamental reason. It just wasn't implemented because it isn't very useful. I don't know any language which implements it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: `f32` is almost certainly IEEE 754 single precision, which is a binary floating point format. As such, any f32 number can be written in binary, but `0.1` in decimal can not be exactly stored in either. Some languages have hexadecimal literals for exact floating point values.

Comment: There is [a discussion about this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2494) on rust-lang/rfcs.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Binary.html) for `std::fmt::Binary` provides a hint:

> The alternate flag, #, adds a 0b in front of the output.

Basically, for every numerical literal expression in Rust, there is a formatter that can print it. If `f32` were to implement `std::fmt::Binary`, this could be seen as making an opinionated statement on what binary floating point literals should look like, even when the language itself doesn't support them and quite possibly never will.

In the early pre-1.0 days there was actually an experimental [syntax extension](https://github.com/rust-lang-deprecated/hexfloat) for hexadecimal floating point literals that was removed before 1.0 stabilization. Occasionally there is still some [discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1433) of the issue, but no plans for adding it to the language, let alone its binary cousin.

Comment: `what binary floating point literals should look like` From https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html they should specifically look like "the “binary32” type defined in IEEE 754-2008".

Comment: @KamilCuk The only "literal format" (the standard uses the term "external character sequence") that IEEE 754-2008 explicitly specifies is a hexadecimal-based one. If you mean it should look like a sequence of 32 '0' and '1' characters representing the actual bits in memory, that's the kind of opinionated statement I mean, since neither Rust docs nor IEEE 754-2008 actually specify that.