# How do i convert a float to the integer with the same byte representation?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

In rust, i want to convert a `&f64` to an `&i64` where it doesn't change the bytes but how to read them. So I want my float bytes read as an integer, like in the fast inverse squareroot algorithm of "quake III" (in C++) where they use:

```cpp
                                     // x is given to the function as float
      int i = *(int*)&x;            // store floating-point bits in integer
```

I tried something like this:

```rust
let mut i : i64 = *(&x as &i64)
```

and got the following error:

```
let mut i: i64 = *(&x as &i64);
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types or to coerce to a specific trait object
```

Comment: You ask how to convert a reference but what your code actually does is convert a *value* (by type punning). Is an answer that just converts from `f64` to the `i64` with the same bits a good answer? Or do you really need to turn a reference into a reference of another type?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377657/3650362) answer your question?

Comment: Yes that would fit the question, because of some weird maths going on in floating point numbers as bits, the same bits as int would be something about the log() of the squareroot. To utilize this i need that conversion but i haven't found another way than saying the program that the value it tries to read is an int (where it was originally a float) with tue use of references.

Comment: To apply the dupe here: `let mut i = x.to_bits() as i64`

Comment: You can either use a union (unsafe) or mem::transmute (unsafe aswell)